# Show changes to HTML5 canvas immediately

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on this wallpaper generator using HTML5 canvas.  (https://github.com/arnav-t/pursuit-wallpapers)
It generates patterns using curves of pursuit.
I want the generation process to be animated and visible to the user.
The lines are drawn over a for loop but they only show up at the end when the loop ends (can be seen in action in the link provided). Why does this happen?

The magic happens in a for loop where I draw lines repeatedly like this:

```
for (let i=0; i < comp; ++i) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = // something          
    ctx.moveTo( // somewhere );
    ctx.lineTo( // somewhere ) ;    
    ctx.lineWidth = // something
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

I tried adding a delay between each frame by `setTimeout()` but that didn't help.

Comment: Use either a setInterval as the loop or my personal recommendation: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @kemicofa why recommend an interval? `requestAnimationFrame` was built specifically to maintain performance while not clogging up the synchronous pipeline with unnecessary rendering.

Comment: Show exactly how you tried to add a delay between each frame using `setTimeout`.  Don't tell us that you tried it and it didn't work, add how you tried it exactly within the question.  If you just put it between the `ctx.*` calls, that's not how the function works.

Comment: I threw the code in a fiddle and split out the drawing into its own function then use recursion to wait 10ms between the loops http://jsfiddle.net/coxpftd5/

Comment: @IrkenInvader Thanks, your suggestion works perfectly. I even gained a few insights about the patterns from the animation.

Comment: I've deployed the changes. Thanks for the help, everyone.
https://arnav-t.github.io/pursuit-wallpapers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript runs asynchronously. The `for` loop executes first, then it looks for the ***i*** value, which is ***comp*** at the end of loop's execution, and then outputs `setTimeOut` ***comp*** times, one for each loop iteration. You will only see the last execution's results all the time. Instead of using a for loop and a setTimeOut you can try this:

```
var maxlimit = 0;

function redrawCanvas() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = // something          
    ctx.moveTo( // somewhere );
    ctx.lineTo( // somewhere ) ;    
    ctx.lineWidth = // something
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    if(maxlimit < comp) {
        maxlimit++;
        setTimeout(redrawCanvas, 100);
    }
}
```

Let me know if that was helpful!